# REST API how to handle fewer results than LIMIT

Tags: rest

I have a REST API that returns a list of products based on input params. The Request body looks like this:

```
{
      "param1": "xxx",
      "param2": "yyy",
      "limit": 50
}
```

The response looks like:

```
{
    "products": [
        543535,
        234324,
        5354,
        5354333
    ]
}
```

How should I handle the situation when I return fewer products than than the user specified limit?
The use case is valid, so no errors should be returned but I want to notify my clients that there are fewer usable products than the specified limit.

So far I can think of two approaches:

1. Send a HTTP 206 Partial Content code. I would prefer this method since it's the least intrusive and it makes sense from a business logic point of view. However, I am unsure if this is a correct usage of the HTTP 206 code or clean REST API design.
2. Add a tag in the response body stating the obvious, like this:

{
"message": "Fewer products than requested.",
"products": [
543535,
234324,
5354,
5354333
]
}

I personally do not like this approach since just looks like stating the obvious and clutters the response body.

Are there any other approaches that I could use to raise some sort of "soft error" for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

> Send a HTTP 206 Partial Content code. I would prefer this method since it's the least intrusive and it makes sense from a business logic point of view. However, I am unsure if this is a correct usage of the HTTP 206 code or clean REST API design.

It is neither correct usage nor clean REST design.

Status codes are meta data of the [transport documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) domain.  Business logic justifications are not relevant.  One of the central themes of REST is that the semantics of the self describing messages are the same for all resources on the internet.

[206 Partial Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-4.1) comes from our range requests standard - indicating that the payload of the response is NOT a complete representation of the resource, but instead only a slice of it.

```
     HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
     Date: Wed, 15 Nov 1995 06:25:24 GMT
     Last-Modified: Wed, 15 Nov 1995 04:58:08 GMT
     Content-Range: bytes 21010-47021/47022
     Content-Length: 26012
     Content-Type: image/gif

     ... 26012 bytes of partial image data ...
```

In your case, the representation being returned is a complete representation of the resource, so 206 is not appropriate.  [200 OK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) is the semantically correct status code to use.

Including domain specific meta data in your representations, on the other hand, is completely appropriate.  It becomes, in effect, just another field in your message schema.